# Dictionary output is convert to string in requestText in flask python?

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

I am sending a dictionary output using flash response to the HTML end is converted to a string

```
@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    def inner():
        for x in [{"EntID" : 3, "x" : 100, "y" : 400},{"abc":"400"}]:
            time.sleep(10)

            yield '%s\n' % x



    return flask.Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')
```

In the HTML side,

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '{{ url_for('stream') }}');
xhr.send();


setInterval(function() {
    var stuff = xhr.responseText;
    output_1.textContent = xhr.responseText;
    output_2.textContent = xhr.responseText;
    output_3.textContent = xhr.responseText;
}, 1000);
```

The output is `{"EntID" : 3, "x" : 100, "y" : 400}`
But I want output as

```
output_1.textContent :3
output_2.textContent: 100
output_3.textContent : 400
```

Comment: maybe format text befor you send to HTML

Comment: how about `xhr.responseText["EntID"]` or something similar in JavaScript ? OR maybe JavaScript has `for`-loop which can get values from dictionary. It seems you have to learn JavaScript for this.

Comment: you may have to use [JSON.parser](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) to convert string `{"EntID" : 3, "x" : 100, "y" : 400}` to dictionary in JavaScript - `var stuff = JSON.parser(xhr.responseText);` and use `output_1.textContent = stuff.EntID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use module `json` to create correct JSON data which later JavaScript can convert back to dictionary.

```
 yield json.dumps(x)
```

and

```
 var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

But it need also to remember old length of `xhr.responseText` and compare with new length because it will have all data from all `yields` and you have to get only new text.

```
var old_position = 0;
var new_position = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    new_position = xhr.responseText.length;

    if(new_position != old_position) {
        var text = xhr.responseText.substr(old_position, new_position);

        //alert(text);

        old_position = new_position;

        var data = JSON.parse(text);

        output_1.textContent = data.EntID;
        output_2.textContent = data.x;
        output_3.textContent = data.y;
    }        
}, 1000);
</script>''')
```

The only problem which I left is that you send different data in every yield - differnt dictonary with different keys.

---

Minimal working code which you can put in one file and run.

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template_string
import time
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
output_1.textContent: <span id="output1"></span><br/>
output_2.textContent: <span id="output2"></span><br/>
output_3.textContent: <span id="output3"></span><br/>

<script>
var output_1 = document.getElementById('output1');
var output_2 = document.getElementById('output2');
var output_3 = document.getElementById('output3');

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '{{ url_for('stream') }}');
xhr.send();

var old_position = 0;
var new_position = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    new_position = xhr.responseText.length;

    if(new_position != old_position) {
        var text = xhr.responseText.substr(old_position, new_position);

        alert(text);

        old_position = new_position;

        var data = JSON.parse(text);

        output_1.textContent = data.EntID;
        output_2.textContent = data.x;
        output_3.textContent = data.y;
    }        
}, 1000);
</script>''')

@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    def inner():
        for x in [{"EntID": 3, "x": 100, "y": 400}, {"abc": "400"}]:
            time.sleep(5)
            yield json.dumps(x)

    return Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: I did the JSON dump and parse part. But, length matching is good logic. Thanks, I learnt a new thing from you.